# Make a function thread safe

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to understand why some functions fail with threading in python.
For example, I'm trying to use `VideoCapture` to grab an image from a webcam.
This example works fine:

```
from VideoCapture import Device

cam = Device()
cam.saveSnapshot('image.jpg')
```

But when I put it on a thread I get an error.

```
import threading
from VideoCapture import Device

def grab():
    cam = Device()
    cam.saveSnapshot('image.jpg')

thr = threading.Thread(target=grab)
thr.start()
thr.join()
```

> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\VideoCapture__init__.py", line 60,
>   in **init**
>       self.dev = vidcap.new_Dev(devnum, showVideoWindow) vidcap.Error: Creation of the filter graph failed.

According to [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911382/videocapture-capture-graph-error), this function is not thread-safe. So is there any workaround to bypass similar issues like this? I tried to use `threading.lock` but got the same error. If I need to change the code, which part should I check?

Comment: Try to get the cam outside the thread and pass it to the thread

Comment: @AndreaBellizzi You are right but actually I'm using it with a schedule which has builtin thread so I can't simply put it outside of the thread.

Comment: If you're not having shared states between threads, you could simply try using `multiprocessing` instead of `multithreading`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a direct way to fix it, but importing the module inside the thread fixed that, I'm not sure if this applies to other modules.

```
import threading

def grab():
    from VideoCapture import Device
    cam = Device()
    cam.saveSnapshot('image.jpg')
    del cam
thr = threading.Thread(target=grab)
thr.start()
thr.join()
```