# How to avoid memory out error when using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have about 600 URL which every 10 seconds I want to update data from there and have some process on them and I have to check all at the same time.

I have found 3 codes for doing this.

code 1:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
agents = 600
pool = ThreadPool(agents)
pool.map(myfunction,inputs)
```

when I use this code without having any problem with the memory I get results but they are not correct. for example, the results of URL(1) are mixed with other URLs.

In the second and third codes, I don't have such a problem and the results are great. but they make memory full and program crashes.

code 2:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
agents = 600
pool = mp.Pool(agents)
pool.map(myfunction,inputs,chunksize=1)
```

code 3:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
procs=[]
for input in inputs:
    proc = Process(target=myfunction,args=(input,))
    procs.append(proc)
    proc.start()
for proc in procs:
    proc.join()
```

I was wondering is there any possible way to fix this problem? or at least how i can increase kernel memory to continue the process? it is  important to process all links at the same time. I cannot change that.
thanks

Comment: Re, "...the results of URL(1) are mixed with other URLs." That may mean that `myfunction` is not "thread safe." What does `myfunction()` do?

Comment: it has a while loop and for the period of time at every 10-second checks URL updates and have some mathematics process on them. after that, it makes a plot and sends it to a telegram bot.

Comment: So, you're trying to create one thread for each of 600 URLs, and each thread periodically polls the remote site? That sounds like a bad idea.  I would have a loop in the main thread. It would periodically submit 600 short-lived tasks to the pool, and I would limit the pool to a much smaller number of workers. I don't have a lot of experience with such things, but I'd maybe start with around 30 workers, and then experiment to see how higher or lower numbers change the performance.

Comment: I think you mean that for example in code 2, I bring out while loop out of myfunction and use it before `pool.map(myfunction,inputs,chunksize=1)` and set number of workers for example to 50. am I right? in that way I will not be able to control the refresh time to 10s and it tooks about 1 minute.

Comment: IDK. Maybe you just need to throw more hardware at the problem. But going back to your "code 1," which according to you does _not_ run out of memory, It sounds as if the problem there is that `myfunction()` is not thread safe. If you want to get help with that, then you'll have to include the definition of `myfunction()` in your question body.

Comment: thank you so much for your time. you mentioned a good point, i will try to find a way to make `myfunction` safe thread.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I found how to make function thread-safe. it worked for me. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287923/make-a-function-thread-safe).i wanted to thanks again for your useful hint.